# BIM360 Docs transfer protocol

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have a question from a customer that wants to know which transfer protocol does BIM 360 Docs use to upload data?

Answer (score 0):

The Forge APIs are a collection of Web APIs in the REST style. Therefore, it goes with HTTP/HTTPs protocol for sure.

Here is a reference for HTTP/HTTPs protocol:

https://www.izooto.com/blog/understanding-http-https-protocols

Hope it helps.